# When should I use a wait function like MsgWaitForMultipleObjects, and when shouldn't I?

Tags: windows, winapi, window

So I am trying to understand the message processing code of Unreal Engine on Windows OS, and I didn't find any frequent usage of the function MsgWaitForMultipleObjects or MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx in the message pumping code.
The engine message pumping goes like this:

```
MSG Message;

    // standard Windows message handling
    while(PeekMessage(&Message, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    { 
        TranslateMessage(&Message);
        DispatchMessage(&Message); 
    }
```

For context, this code will run every frame one to three times, meaning the code will be executed each 2 - 5 milliseconds on average throughout the running time of the application. A) Does that make wait functions unnecessary? or am I missing something here!

B) Is there any rough estimation of how long an application could be busy doing 'other stuff' before processing incoming messages? For instance if an application only processes messages every 50 millisecond, is that a bad practice? or is that a reasonable way of doing it? And what if the period became 500 milliseconds and so?

Comment: `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx` used when you need wait not only for windows messages, but for some handles and/or apc

Comment: @RbMm but does that mean it is ok not to use it for messages in the case that you keep checking with PeekMessage instead?

Comment: of course if you not need extended functionality, you can use GetMessage or PeekMessage

Comment: @RbMm cool, thanks for stepping by.

Comment: [Creating Windows in Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-windows-in-threads) has a clear explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MsgWaitForMultipleObjects/etc if you need to both handle window message processing and kernel handle or alertable waits in a single thread. If you are only doing message processing then simply use a normal GetMessage based message loop, if only doing kernel handle or alertable waits then use WaitForMultipleObjects as appropriate.

Comment: So kernel handle and alertable waits, and thus calling MsgWaitForMultipleObjects can be done in a thread that is not the window-creating thread? This is confusing because AFAIK message processing WndProc is always called on the window creating thread?

Comment: No, messages will only ever be posted to the thread that created a window, but it allows combining a peek message loop with waiting for kernel handles and APCs. I don't know that I've ever combined handle waits and message handling but I've definitely combined APCs and message handling. Although, even there you have to be careful because if you open a standard modal dialog then a different message loop will be invoked, one that doesn't perform the alertable wait.

Comment: @phy Messages are associated with threads, not windows. You can have threads that are message receivers that do not own any windows at all.

Comment: @IInspectable does that apply to WM_INPUT messages as well? In other words can a window-less thread receive WM_INPUT messages?

Comment: @phy A window-less thread can receive **any** message. Whether Raw Input can be configured to work without a (message-only) window is something you will have to investigate. The main point here is that messages are associated with threads. The fact that threads can also own windows is coincidental.

Comment: @IInspectable I get what you're saying, thanks for your time.